# sorting list of tuples doesnt work

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

This is my first question here =):
My problem is what is stated in the title. I want to simply sort a list of tuples with 2 elements. It should work with sorted but it still returns the unsorted List,... it seems to do nothing.
Input:

```
#"L =[(0, 1), (4, 6), (5, 7), (0, 6), (0, 4), (2, 5)]" Its an example.
for line in stdin:
 L = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
 n = L[0]
 V = [i for i in range(n)]
 edgelist = L[1:]
 EDGE = [(edgelist[i],edgelist[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(edgelist)-1,2) ]
 mK = missingKnots(edgelist)
 EDGE = sorted(EDGE)
 EDGE = list(set(EDGE))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (4, 6), (5, 7), (0, 6), (0, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Should be:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 4), (0, 6), (2, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)]
```

Unsorted =(.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please tag the question with the programming language in which your code is written.  I *think* it's Python, but I'm not confident enough to tag it for you.

Comment: Ok thank you! @John Bollinger

Comment: why just not `L.sort()`? I don't see sense of other manipulations

Comment: That code does not generate that output.  No `print` for example.  Show the actual code you are having a problem with.

Comment: What is the point of constructing a set from the return value of `sorted()`?  Sets are unordered; likely you lose whatever order you obtained from `sorted()` that way, to no apparent purpose.

Comment: I tried this too but it still doesnt sort? I dont know why.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There may be multiple duplicated items in my list and i want to get rid of that by set.

Comment: Python indentation should be 4 spaces per block, definitely not 1 - it's almost impossible to tell what's indented.

Comment: If you want to squash dupes by constructing a set, then do it *before* you sort.

Comment: John Billinger i tried this also,... and i changed it now but it still doesnt sort the tuples.

Comment: You removed the bug from the posted question- which will make this very hard to follow for someone else with a similar problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort and return new list:

```
>>> L =[(0, 1), (4, 6), (5, 7), (0, 6), (0, 4), (2, 5)]
>>> sorted(L)
[(0, 1), (0, 4), (0, 6), (2, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)]
```

Sort in place:

```
>>> L.sort()
>>> L
[(0, 1), (0, 4), (0, 6), (2, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)]
```

Don't do the `set()` afterward.  Sets are unordered.

```
>>> list(set(L))
[(0, 1), (4, 6), (5, 7), (0, 6), (0, 4), (2, 5)] # now it's messed up again.
```

Ideally, to sort and remove duplicates:

```
>>> L = [(0, 1), (4, 6), (5, 7), (0, 6), (0, 4), (2, 5), (0, 1)]
>>> sorted(set(L))
[(0, 1), (0, 4), (0, 6), (2, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)]
```

Comment: sort last, not first.  The `set()` screws up your sort.

Comment: You need to sort it after you've converted it to a set. A set has no order, therefore your sorting is being lost.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen thank you! I look if its working w/o set.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen thanks. Now it works, I should have known that set screws it... but now i defenitly do!

Answer (score 1):

With lambda expression, you can customise the rules of sorting.

```
EDGE = [(0, 1), (4, 6), (5, 7), (0, 6), (0, 4), (2, 5)]
EDGE = sorted(EDGE, key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]) )
print EDGE
```

result:

```
 [(0, 1), (0, 4), (0, 6), (2, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)]
```